# laravel 5.3 new Auth::routes()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Recently I start to use laravel 5.3 to write a blog, but I have a question after run `php artisan make:auth`

when I run this, it will generate routes in my `web.php`

this is the code in it:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
```

Then I run `php artisan route:list`, I find lots of actions, like LoginController@login...

But I didn't find these actions in my `App\Http\Controllers\Auth`, where are these?

And also what is the `Auth::routes()` stand for, I can't find the routes about Auth.

I need someone help, thank you to answer my question

Comment: Am I the only one who now hates all those Laravel magics?

Comment: I don't mind the laravel magics, if only they were documented... and worked consistently without having to walk widdershins around the server while chanting php artisan..what?

Comment: Everything Laravel is not for developers, it's for companies and novice users who want to bring up new apps fast and easy, even their documentation. I'd still prefer Codeigniter if I had a choice.

Comment: Read this guide: https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-auth-routes-email-verification-reset-password-authentication-registration-routes-fb82b3337150

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Talk about magic, now there's laravel jetstream...

Answer (score 244, accepted):

`Auth::routes()` is just a helper class that helps you generate all the routes required for user authentication. You can browse the code here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php instead.

Here are the routes

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the ../Routing/Router.php and now I know how the routes work.But where is the Auth static method routes()? I still can't find it, forgive me I am a laravel beginner...

Comment: Auth::routes method is here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php and its calling the Router function anyway. 

Please mark this as answer if this have helped you, thanks.

Comment: `Auth` is a *facade* and will be defined in `config/app.php` You will find the class that acts as its provider in that configuration file.

Comment: Have same but getting error : `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:`, and another api's running fine.

Comment: `$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');` not able to run `Auth` api's

Comment: As of *5.7* you can also pass options to the Auth::routes()
Like `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);` To disable register.
The follow options are available `register`, `reset` and `verify`.
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1147

Comment: For Laravel 5.7 and 5.8 I suggest reading this guide: https://medium.com/@panjeh/laravel-auth-routes-email-verification-reset-password-authentication-registration-routes-fb82b3337150

Comment: I removed Auth::routes() and add those detailed routes. It is totally wasting my time to search a document for it.

Answer (score 73):

Here's **Laravel 5.7**, **Laravel 5.8**, **Laravel 6.0**, **Laravel 7.0**, and **Laravel 8.0** (note a minor bc change in 6.0 to the email verification route).

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

// Confirm Password (added in v6.2)
Route::get('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm')->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', 'Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm');

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify'); // v6.x
/* Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify'); // v5.x */
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

You can verify these routes here:

- v**5.7** https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1176
- v**5.8** https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1151
- v**6.0** https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1178
- v**7.0** https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/2.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php (This has been moved to the laravel/ui package)
- v**8.0** https://github.com/laravel/ui/blob/3.x/src/AuthRouteMethods.php (No changes other than adding optional namespace)

Comment: There was indeed a small change from 5.8 to 6.x as your links show: The route for the email verification link should be `'email/verify/{id}/{hash}'`. Otherwise the hash can’t be verified and a 403 error will be thrown saying “This action is unauthorized”.

Answer (score 47):

Auth routes for Laravel 5.3 instead Auth::routes().
I hope it helps...

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {

// Login Routes...
    Route::get('login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);
    Route::post('login', ['as' => 'login.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login']);
    Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'logout', 'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout']);

// Registration Routes...
    Route::get('register', ['as' => 'register', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm']);
    Route::post('register', ['as' => 'register.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
    Route::get('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm']);
    Route::post('password/email', ['as' => 'password.email', 'uses' => 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail']);
    Route::get('password/reset/{token}', ['as' => 'password.reset.token', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm']);
    Route::post('password/reset', ['as' => 'password.reset.post', 'uses' => 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset']);
});
```

So if you change some names of these routes, remember to also change in views the actions of the posts!

Comment: Thanks but you don't need to 'middleware' => ['web'] because of : 
out of the box, the web middleware group is automatically applied to your  routes/web.php file by the RouteServiceProvider.

Comment: @panjeh this appears to be true for the main `routes/web.php` file. However, for any such file in a vendor dir (ie. if you are trying to move the auth stuff into a package), you are required to add the web middleware yourself.

Answer (score 15):

For **Laravel 5.5.x**

```
// Authentication Routes...
$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
$this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
$this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Answer (score 9):

function call order:

1. (Auth)Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth@routes
   (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php)
2. (App)Illuminate\Foundation\Application@auth
3. (Route)Illuminate\Routing\Router

it's route like this:

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\AuthController@login');
    $this->get('logout', 'Auth\AuthController@logout');
    // Registration Routes...
    $this->get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm');
    $this->post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
    // Password Reset Routes...
    $this->get('password/reset/{token?}', 'Auth\PasswordController@showResetForm');
    $this->post('password/email', 'Auth\PasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail');
    $this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\PasswordController@reset');
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L298

Comment: This answer actually sheds light on the question asked by OP. Thanks @SilentCat.

Comment: I thought it would be good to verbally explain what happens in these 3 steps above: `Auth::routes()` - the Auth facade - retrieves the `Router` object instance from Laravel container and calls its pre-existing method `auth`. `auth` in turn defines the routes and their respective controllers that were generated by `php artisan make:auth`. This is it.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me with **Laravel 5.6**.

In the file `web.php`, just replace:

```
Auth::routes();
```

By:

```
//Auth::routes();
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('admin/login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('admin/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

And remove the **Register** link in the two files below:

```
welcome.blade.php
layouts/app.blade.php
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are searching these same routes for laravel 7 version you'll find it here `Vendor/laravel/ui/src/AuthRouteMethods.php`

Answer (score 5):

**For Laravel 8:**

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController;

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class,'login']);
Route::post('logout',  [LoginController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');

// Confirm Password 
Route::get('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'showConfirmForm'])->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'confirm']);

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', [VerificationController::class, 'show'])->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend',  [VerificationController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');

// Home
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
```

Answer (score 4):

if you are in laravel 5.7 and above `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);` in web.php

more possible options are as:

```
Auth::routes([
  'register' => false, // Routes of Registration
  'reset' => false,    // Routes of Password Reset
  'verify' => false,   // Routes of Email Verification
]);
```

Comment: For apps where public is not allowed register and password reset is not allowed via email, This works best.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the command `php artisan route:list`, which gives a list of all registered app routes (including `Auth::routes()` and `Passport::routes()` if registered)

Answer (score 0):

the loginuser class uses a trait called `AuthenticatesUsers`

if you open that trait you will see the functions (this applies for other controllers)
`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;`

here is the trait code https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php

sorry for the bad format, im using my phone

also `Auth::routes()` it just calls a function that returns the auth routes thats it (i think)

Comment: Yes, i look through the Auth/ dir, but I am not find the method,like App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm,where can I find the method after @, I cost much time to find it, but now I also can't find it..I am new to laravel..

Comment: here is the full path `vendor\laravel\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords` , if you want to change this or something , dont change this, just add the same method to ur controller and then change it,

Comment: @Achraf Khouadja, It seems you master laravel. I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047583/how-to-add-dynamic-dropdown-list-column-on-laravel-5-3-registration

Answer (score 0):

After I ran
-composer require laravel/ui
-php artisan ui:auth

I started seeing the classes in the Auth folder. Http/Controller/Auth

Answer (score 0):

In the Http/Controller/Auth you can find all the controllers regarding authentication. I was having issue redirect but then I made a new const in RouteServiceProvider.php under Http/Providers... And used it in my controllers to redirect to the page I want...
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::ADMIN;

Answer (score 0):

Works for Laravel 10

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController;

Route::get('login', [LoginController::class, 'showLoginForm'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [LoginController::class,'login']);
Route::post('logout',  [LoginController::class,'logout'])->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register');
Route::post('register', [RegisterController::class, 'register']);

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showLinkRequestForm'])->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'sendResetLinkEmail'])->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'showResetForm'])->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', [ForgotPasswordController::class, 'reset'])->name('password.update');

// Confirm Password 
Route::get('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'showConfirmForm'])->name('password.confirm');
Route::post('password/confirm', [ConfirmPasswordController::class, 'confirm']);

// Email Verification Routes...
Route::get('email/verify', [VerificationController::class, 'show'])->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerificationController::class, 'verify'])->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend',  [VerificationController::class, 'resend'])->name('verification.resend');
```