# InvalidArgumentException Route [login] not defined. in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

Route [login] not defined.
C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\MMICTLTD\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php
**Guys I need your help, I keep getting this error of route login not defined, am running laravel 5.6**
Am trying to setup multiple authentication but this error is having me so frustrated. Any help

My handler.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
    use Request;
    use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
    use Response;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
         protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
         {
          if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            // code...
            return response()->json(['error' => 'unauthenticated.'], 401);
          }

          $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);

          switch ($guard) {
            case 'admin':
              $login = 'admin.login';
              break;

            default:
                return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
              break;
          }

    }
}
```

My Routes

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/


Route::get('/',[
    'uses' => 'ShopController@getHome',
    'as' => 'layouts.master',
]);

Route::get('/shop',[
    'uses' => 'ShopController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'pages.shop',
]);
Route::get('/blog',[
    'uses' => 'ShopController@getblog',
    'as' => 'pages.blog',
]);
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::GET('admin/home','AdminController@index');       

Route::GET('login','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
Route::POST('login','Admin\LoginController@login');                  
Route::POST('admin-password/email','Admin\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('admin.password.email'); 
Route::GET('admin-password/reset', 'Admin\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('admin.password.request');
Route::POST('admin-password/reset','Admin\ResetPasswordController@reset'); 
Route::GET('admin-password/reset/{token}', 'Admin\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('admin.password.reset');
```

Answer (score 1):

You named route as `admin.login`.  Use

```
return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
```

Instead

```
return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
```

Comment: Alos your routes are overwritten with `Auth::routes()` , [Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49870403/2815635)

Answer (score 0):

Move this line

```
Route::GET('login','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
```

above this line

```
Auth::routes();
```

SO it will look like this :

```
 Route::GET('login','Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('admin.login');
 Auth::routes();
```

And use this line for redirect

```
return redirect()->guest(route('admin.login'));
```

I hove it might help you.