# Laravel Auth Login Page Just Refreshes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.4. I ran the make:auth command to scaffold out my auth controllers and views. I can register a new account without issue as it is showing up in my database. However when I try to login, the login page simply refreshes without any errors being thrown. In the login controller I have the redirect set to '/home' but this isn't happening. Any idea what could be causing this? I have a feeling this is because I made the required tweaks to allow users to login with a username rather than email. But I'm not sure what is causing my login not to work when everything else works fine.

Below is my login controller.

```
use AuthenticatesUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}


public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a quick check to see if the route is being handled.

You might have to add `Auth::routes();` in your `web.php`

**Resource:**
[laravel 5.3 new Auth::routes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196968/laravel-5-3-new-authroutes)

Answer (score 0):

Once you've run `php artisan make:auth` you need to also run the migrations with `php artisan migrate` have you done this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using `Laravel 8.0` and found no helpful response over the internet... until I taught of checking the APP_URL set in my env...

Because I have other apps set up on other ports on the same localhost, I simply changed `APP_URL` from `http://localhost` to `http://localhost:8003/`, i.e, specifying the port this App is on.

*Other steps I took that may contributes include generating new `APP_KEY` and  refreshing my migration.*

It's been many years, but, this took my 3 days to figure... I hope it helps someone.