# There isn't displays authentication block in Laravel project

Tags: laravel, authentication, authorization, laravel-ui

I'm completely new in Laravel. I don't understand why authentication block doesn't displays after I installed `laravel/ui` and `php artisan make:auth` command. These pages have been added. But there aren't any special routes in routes list. [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tLEJ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't use image for display codes. Try put here directly.

Comment: Please put web.php in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In ***web.php*** you have to use

```
Auth::routes();
```

Comment: There is Auth::routes();

Comment: You should read : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196968/laravel-5-3-new-authroutes